# Call artisan in laravel with migrate:make

Tags: php, laravel, migration, laravel-artisan

Run artisan commands from routes or controller. If you want run your migrations make:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:make');
```

but have not migrate name.
How to run command : "migrate:make NameMigrate" and use Artisan::call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't like the idea of creating migration in controller, but you surely can perform it.

Laravel 4:

```
Artisan::call('migrate:make', ['name' => 'migration_name']);
```

Laravel 5:

```
Artisan::call('make:migration', ['name' => 'migration_name']);
```

---

Don't forget to grant write permission to `migrations` folder so your application can write files to that folder.

Laravel 4: `chmod 777 database/migrations`

Laravel 5: `chmod 777 app/database/migrations`

Comment: What if we want to pass table name as an argument just like name?I'd tried with `Artisan::call('make:migration', ['name' => 'migration_name','table'=>'table name']);` But it Didn't worked!! Any Clue?

Comment: @SmitShah the argument name should be `--table`  as per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#generating-migrations)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8

```php
Artisan::call('make:migration NameMigrate']);
```